# traversing object in react but exiting due to return statement issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component that is accepting a json object from an api call. I want to traverse the folder/file json object and render them inside the component return statement in a tree manor. I am calling the traveseFolder cunction within the html of react componenet. I want it traverse through the ojbect and render each objects name and path with each iteration. I noticed that they only way for me to render is to return the div that is dynamically generated. The issue is that the return call is exiting the traversal function. How can i get around this to render and then keep going through the function...

here is my code:

```
    const traverseFolder = (current:any) => {
        console.log(current)
        for(let i = 0; i < current.length; i++){
            // console.log(current[i]['text'])
            if(current[i]){
                console.log(current[i])
                if(current[i]['children'].length > 0){
                    console.log('# of children: ' + current[i]['children'].length)
                    console.log('folder found: ' + current[i]['text'])
                    return(
                        <div>
                            <span>{current[i]['text']}</span>
                        </div>
                    )
                    for(let j = 0; j < current[i]['children'].length; j++){
                        traverseFolder(current[i]['children'][j])
                    }
                }
                if(current[i]['children'].length === 0){
                    console.log('file found: ' + current[i]['text'])
                    return(
                        <div>
                            <span>{current[i]['text']}</span>
                            <span>{current[i]['path']}</span>
                        </div>
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return (
        <Dialog
            className={classNames(themeClass, styles.helpDialog)}
            title="Help"
            icon="help"
            isOpen={isOpen}
            onClose={mainStore.hideHelpDialog}
        >
        <div>
            {
                folderLoading ? (
                    <div>
                        {
                            traverseFolder(files)
                        }
                    </div>                    
                ) : (
                    <Spinner />
                )
            }

        </div>
        </Dialog>
    );
```

Comment: It's exiting because you have a return in a for loop, which would only respect the outer context, rather than the loop context. I believe there are several ways of achieving what you're trying to do, e.g. creating an array to hold the values and return at the end of the execution; using a map or reduce etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here case is you are returning dom and code below return statement is not executing. You can add folder travarsel logic inside return statement. Code can be done as follow.

```
const traverseFolder = (current:any) => {
        console.log(current)
        for(let i = 0; i < current.length; i++){
            // console.log(current[i]['text'])
            if(current[i]){
                console.log(current[i])
                if(current[i]['children'].length > 0){
                    console.log('# of children: ' + current[i]['children'].length)
                    console.log('folder found: ' + current[i]['text'])
                    return(
                        <div>
                            <span>{current[i]['text']}</span>
                            {
                              current[i]['children'].map((ele) => 
                                traverseFolder(ele)
                            }
                        </div>
                    )
                }
                if(current[i]['children'].length === 0){
                    console.log('file found: ' + current[i]['text'])
                    return(
                        <div>
                            <span>{current[i]['text']}</span>
                            <span>{current[i]['path']}</span>
                        </div>
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return (
        <Dialog
            className={classNames(themeClass, styles.helpDialog)}
            title="Help"
            icon="help"
            isOpen={isOpen}
            onClose={mainStore.hideHelpDialog}
        >
        <div>
            {
                folderLoading ? (
                    <div>
                        {
                            traverseFolder(files)
                        }
                    </div>                    
                ) : (
                    <Spinner />
                )
            }

        </div>
        </Dialog>
    );
```